# End of object lifetime if its storage is partially reused

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, lifetime

Starting from C++20 and as of the latest standard draft, it appears like the rules for the end of an object's lifetime are not super clear when the object's storage is partially "re-used". The existing answers on StackOverflow that I've found are not fully conclusive on this matter.

Given the assumption that **double** and **uint64_t** alignment and storage space would be exactly the same, I've got the following question from an code example below:

will `new (&a->c1) uint64_t{4}` below end the lifetime of object a?

```
struct A
{
   double d;   
   int i;
   double c1;
   double d1;
   double d2;
};


int main () {

A* a = new A{};
uint64_t* i = new (&a->c1) uint64_t{4}; //will this end lifetime of a? It would clearly end the lifetime of a.c1
*i = 124; //this must be UB because of strict-aliasing rules
return 0;
}
```

The standard clearly stipulates the rules at the end of an object's lifetime:

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.3

> - if T is a non-class type, the object is destroyed, or
> - if T is a class type, the destructor call starts, or
> - the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is **not nested** within o ([intro.object]).

Then formally the object is nested in the following conditions:

> An object a is nested within another object b if: (4.1) a is a
> subobject of b, or (4.2) b **provides storage** for a, or (4.3) there
> exists an object c where a is nested within c, and c is nested within
> b.

For our code example we are bound to

> subobject of b, or (4.2) b **provides storage** for a, or (4.3) there

Then the standard defines what **provides storage** means

> If a complete object is created ([expr.new]) in storage associated
> with another object e of type “array of N unsigned char” or of type
> “array of N std​::​byte” ([cstddef.syn]), that array provides storage
> for the created object if: (3.1) the lifetime of e has begun and not
> ended, and (3.2) the storage for the new object fits entirely within
> e, and (3.3) there is no array object that satisfies these constraints
> nested within e.

This implies that only arrays of std::byte or unsigned char can **provide storage**...From which I imply that creating **uint64_t{4**} object inside **a's storage** would end the lifetime of object a, as **uint64_t{4}** is not nested in a...Although I'm not really sure about this conclusion.

Comment: `new (&a->c1) int{4}` will lead to undefined behavior, since you try to store an `int` value into a `char`. That makes possible life-time issues moot.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude would you mind putting some link from the standard where it would trigger UB? I don't doubt your words, just want to know it for reference.

Comment: @minex: It is at least potentially UB, as there's no guarantee that `A::c1` is aligned appropriately for an `int`.

Comment: A `char` is typically one byte, while an `int` is typically four. You can't fit four bytes into one byte. Going out of bounds leads to UB. With that said, there are systems in use today where a `char` could be two bytes (but `sizeof(char)` is still defined to be `1`) and other platforms where `int` is two bytes. But you will likely never come across a system where both `char` and `int` are the same size (I never have in my close to 40 years of programming).

Comment: @Nicol Bolas ok, replacing char may be a bad idea, but what if instead of int{4} replacing A::c1 it would be uint64_t{4} replace A::d1? It would have the same alignment and the storage would overlay exactly. Clearly, in C++ it is legal to "re-use" storage and fully replace an object with another object as long as the previous pointer is not used to refer to the new object.

Comment: `char c1[sizeof(int)];` and `new (a->c1) int{4}` could be fine, if the alignment also fits. But why not simply change to use an actual `int` member? Like `struct A { int a; int b; int c; };` and "replace" the `b` member with an `int` value?

Comment: Also, is this just plain curiosity? It's fine, but please tell us (in the question). If not, then please ask about the underlying and actual problem directly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is not from a real-world example, but to clarify a very fundamental understanding of the standard/language. That char was a bad example. I'll change it now to replace double wit h uint64_t so that alignment and storage would exactly overlay on most platforms. My point is that according to the standard, the lifetime of a would end and there is no UB in that, apart from referring to the replaced object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've updated the question to use **double** instead of **char** and **uint64_t** instead of **int** in order to make my point more clear.

Comment: Aggregates are often a grey zone. Here you have a POD class and only reuse one single element storage. Nothing in standard will explicitely say that other elements are still valid, nor the opposite. In real world if you want to be on the safe side, you will avoid code like that. Or if you really need it for performance or compatibility with legacy code, you would write a large comment explaining it, and asking maintainers to check compatibility with the environment (compiler + config)

Comment: @SergeBallesta my point is that according to the standard, the *lifetime of a* is formally ended the moment I start re-using its subobjects as in my example. Although I'm definitely not sure of this as the end of the lifetime section did not mention if the storage has to be re-used *fully or partially*.

Comment: _*i = 124; //this must be UB because of strict-aliasing rules_ Lol?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer do you think otherwise?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There actually are 16 bit DSP from TI having `CHAR_BIT == 16 && sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`. Came across them a few years ago ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will new (&a->c1) uint64_t{4} below end the lifetime of object a?

Not of the object associated with the variable `a`, but the object that `a` points to, i.e. the `A` object, not the `A*` object. Yes, the `A` object's lifetime will end with reuse of (part of) its storage in the new-expression because the object reusing its storage isn't nested within it. The `c1` subobject of the `A` object will also have its lifetime ended since the new object reuses its storage as well without being nested in it. I would also expect that this would end the lifetime of all other subobjects of the `A` object, however currently the standard doesn't seem to say that.

```
*i = 124; //this must be UB because of strict-aliasing rules
```

That's well-defined. `i` is pointing to an object of type `uint64_t` that you created in the previous new-expression. So it can't be an aliasing violation.

After the new-expression you can't use the object that `a` points to any more. In particular you can't access `a.c1` any more, because that (sub)object's lifetime has also ended and you can't access the same memory location through `reinterpret_cast<double*>(i)` because that would indeed be an aliasing violation.

Comment: Right, good that it making sense now. *i = 127 is fine because a lifetime’s was ended and a new object unit64_t was created in it. Thanks!

Comment: _the lifetime of all of its subobjects  … will end_ Why?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Fixed, however that doesn't seem consistent to me. For example, does that mean that I can still e.g. do a `virtual` function call on a pointer to a base class subobject of a most-derived object that had its lifetime ended this way?

Comment: Yes, it is not consistent and all subobjects should die

Comment: @minex That talks about what happens with objects at creation and it also only specifies whether or not objects are subobjects of another object. It doesn't say anything about lifetime of the potential subobject. And as discussed above, I think there is general agreement that _not_ ending the lifetime of all subobjects isn't consistent, but there is some wording missing to actually specify ending their lifetime. Taking the standard as written I don't see anything that would e.g. forbid storing a pointer to `a->d` before the `new` and then accessing through that after the `new`.

Comment: @user17732522 right, **a's**  lifetime ends, and technically a's subjects become complete objects! Correct? Because the link from the standard above says what is to be a subject. I see your point about storing a point of **a->d** as accessing through a itself would be illegal

Comment: @minex Whether simply forming a member reference expression `a->d` is still allowed is a bit unclear. Because `A` is trivial https://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#1 does not apply and also none of the listed UB cases in https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7 apply. It only specifically mentions non-static member function calls. So only https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6.2 remains, which doesn't have a clear intention, see open [CWG issue 1530](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1530). I used the stored pointer to the member to avoid discussing this (and failed in that).

Comment: @minex I don't see any reason that the subobject status should change just because lifetimes end. So the object corresponding to `a->d` will still be a subobject and not a complete object.

Comment: @user17732522 eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6.2 r as I read it, it does not apply for two reasons: 1) **and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released**. we re-use its storage right to replace **c1**? 2)  **any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object** that appears to be the actual pointer which contains the address of the first byte that object occupied

Comment: @user17732522 https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.object-2 formally defines a subobject and when an object is a subject of another object. It clearly says that the host object must be within its lifetime and **a's** lifetime has ended. Hence a->d is no longer a sub-object. This means either its lifetime also must end or it *becomes*(which is nowhere defined as far as I see) a complete object.

Comment: @minex I think that's similar to [CWG issue 1027](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1027). The restrictions placed of basic.life/6 and 7 should apply to the old object even after reuse. Otherwise there is nothing in the standard describing how the pointer `a` will behave after the `new`. For https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.object-2 I interpret it to say that the subobject property is determined at creation by the listed rules, not that at any given point in time the subobject property is determined according to the listed rules.

Comment: @user17732522 Ok fair enough. The standard does say that the properties of the object are established once it has been created. Although the way that the "reuse" word is used to talk about lifetime and object is a bit vague, particularly about *partial* reuse.

Comment: @user17732522 what about my point above ? 2) **any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object** -  that appears to be the actual pointer which contains the address of the first byte that object occupied! This could imply that it is still safe to refer to the pointers of a's subjects. Or you the implementation may just kick off some optimizations to override a's storage because a's lifetime ended after it's storage was *partially* reused?

Comment: @user17732522 but look at C++14 standard, it apparently forbids access to a's subjects through any pointer! ---> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, **any pointer that refers to the storage location where the object** will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways